# PostgreSQL database online

Tags: python, database, postgresql, crud, sharepoint-online

I am developing a CRUD in Python, which will be useful for a project. However, I want to connect the database that I currently have created in PostgreSQL to a kind of online server or online DB, so that in case there is loss of information, it is not necessary to make a recurring backup, but to have all information online or make my computer work as a server. How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It looks like you want a Postgresql server in the "cloud". Take a look at Heroku, AWS, Digital Ocean, and various other cloud vendors. (Heroku has a usable free tier.)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, first you'll want to the install psycopg2 with pip by doing, pip install psycopg2 or use pip3 then you'll want to try an example such as.

```
from psycopg2 import Error

try:
    # Connect to an existing database
    connection = psycopg2.connect(user="postgres",
                                  password="pynative@#29",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="postgres_db")

    # Create a cursor to perform database operations
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    # Print PostgreSQL details
    print("PostgreSQL server information")
    print(connection.get_dsn_parameters(), "\n")
    # Executing a SQL query
    cursor.execute("SELECT version();")
    # Fetch result
    record = cursor.fetchone()
    print("You are connected to - ", record, "\n")

except (Exception, Error) as error:
    print("Error while connecting to PostgreSQL", error)
finally:
    if (connection):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
```

Answer (score -1):

You might want to try the [psycopg2](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/psycopg2/info) library. Psycopg is a PostgreSQL adapter for the Python programming language. It implements PEP 249 with many extensions.

Here is a link: https://pynative.com/python-postgresql-tutorial/